# Validate a function call without calling a function

Tags: python, pydantic

I'd like to know if I can use pydantic to check whether arguments *would* be fit for calling a type hinted function, but *without* calling the function.

For example, given

```
kwargs = {'x': 1, 'y': 'hi'}

def foo(x: int, y: str, z: Optional[list] = None):
    pass
```

I want to check whether `foo(**kwargs)` would be fine according to the type hints. So basically, what `pydantic.validate_call` does, without calling `foo`.

My research led me to [this](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/2127) github issue. The solution works, but it relies on `validate_arguments`, which is deprecated. It cannot be switched for `validate_call`, because its return value doesn't have a `vd` attribute, making the line `validated_function = f.vd` fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the annotations attribute from the function and use it to build a pydantic model using the `type` constructor:

```py
def form_validator_model(func: collections.abc.Callable) -> type[pydantic.BaseModel]:
    ann = func.__annotations__.copy()
    ann.pop('return', None) # Remove the return value annotation if it exists.
    return type(f'{func.__name__}_Validator', (pydantic.BaseModel,), {'__annotations__': ann})

def func(a: str, b: int) -> str:
    return a * b

model = form_validator_model(func)
model(a='hi', b='bye') # raises ValidationError
```

The downside is you can't call the arguments positionally.

Comment: Clever solution, thank you! I'm not sure I understood your final sentence. Did you mean that when using `validate_call`, the call to `func` gets validated correctly even if I use positional arguments, while when using `model` to validate the call prior to using `func`, I must supply keyword arguments?

Comment: Exactly.  I'm sure there's a way to make it work with positional arguments but I'll have to give it some more thought.

Comment: Two caveats: 1. neither your solution nor `validate_call` seem to be able to handle `def f(a: 'hi')`. 2. Your solution will not catch missing required arguments if they don't have a type hint, `validate_call` will.

Comment: You can use [`inspect.Signature.bind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.bind) to support any combination of args and kwargs and lift the keyword-only restriction. It will fail with a `TypeError` if arguments cannot be passed this way (missing kwargs, args, etc.)

Comment: @actual_panda what do you mean by `def f(a: 'hi')` - invalid annotation? Behaviour for invalid hints is not specified in your question. Or is `hi` some existing type (resolvable within the module)? If so, this solution should work.

Comment: @STerliakov I just wanted to point out that `def f(a: 'hi'): pass` is valid Python, but `pydantic.validate_call` can't handle it.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably to make your own dummy function and use `functools.wraps` to copy the signature of your target function:

```py
# The target function
def func(b1: bool, i1: int, i2_opt: int | None = None, *, kw_b1_opt: bool | None = None, kw_i1_opt: int | None = None):
    ...

# Make a validator function
@validate_call
@functools.wraps(func)  # Technically not a wrap, but that's fine.
def validate_func_args(*args, **kwargs):
    return args, kwargs

# These all raise a ValidationError with very nice details:
validate_func_args("boom", 2.0, kw_b1_opt="no", kw_i1_opt="3")
validate_func_args("not-a-boolish-string", 2.0)
validate_func_args(0, 1, unknown_kwarg=2)
validate_func_args(0)  # Missing required arg
validate_func_args(0, 1, 2, "extra_positional_arg")

# As a bonus, you can inspect the validated arguments if you like (or call the
# target function with them without wasting cycles on validating them AGAIN):
validated_args, validated_kwargs = validate_func_args(0, 2.0, kw_b1_opt="no")
validated_args  # -> (False, 2)
validated_kwargs  # -> {'i2_opt': None, 'kw_b1_opt': False, 'kw_i1_opt': None}
```

Note that this approach has none of the shortcomings that are mentioned about the currently accepted answer.

Incidentally, Pydantic might be overkill if the signature type checking is all you're looking for. There are lighter alternatives. The above trick would probably work with `@typechecked` from the `typeguard` package in place of `@validate_call`, for example.

Comment: Ooo!  That is shnazzy!  Nice!